# Mobile Swipe Event With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a simple left/right swipe event to an element.  On swipe some jQuery should be executed. I have tried a number of scripts to achieve this but no success.

Right now I am using this one: https://gianlucaguarini.com/Tocca.js/

I can use the same code in an onclick and it works so I can't see why it doesn't work on swipe.

The issue can be reproduced using the below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="test-swipe" style="background-color: red; min-height: 200px;"></div>

<a id="test-click" href="https://google.com">link</a>   

<br ><br >

<a id="manual-trigger" href="https://google.com">manually trigger the click</a>   

<script>
// On Swipe Left
$("#test-swipe").on('swipeleft',function (e,data){
        console.log(data.x);
        console.log(data.y);
        console.log(data.distance.x);
        console.log(data.distance.y); 
        $("#test-click").click();
});
</script>

<script>
// On Manual Click
$( "#manual-trigger" ).on( "click", function() {
  $("#test-click").click();
});
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Tocca.js/2.0.9/Tocca.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant HTML?  Such as id=my-elment and productView-thumbnail-link (and related).   Ideally in a complete snippet that demonstrates the issue.  See [MCVE],.

Comment: I have updated the original question to include a reproducible example.

Comment: `<a id="manual-trigger" href='` you need to *cancel the default click event* otherwise it just navigates to the href of manual-trigger.   `return false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `swipeleft` is available in JQuery mobile so make sure that you're importing that library.

The other issue is with `click()`. The JQuery selector returns an array of elements so in order to get the one that you want you need to specify an index (0 in this case).

This is the modified line:

```
$("#test-click")[0].click();
```

Demo (one can simulate left sweep by moving pointer keeping the left mouse button pressed):

```js
// On Swipe Left
$("#test-swipe").on('swipeleft', function(e, data) {
  console.log(data.x);
  console.log(data.y);
  console.log(data.distance.x);
  console.log(data.distance.y);
  $("#test-click")[0].click();
});

// On Manual Click
$("#manual-trigger").on("click", function() {
  $("#test-click").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Tocca.js/2.0.9/Tocca.min.js"></script>

<div id="test-swipe" style="background-color: red; min-height: 200px;"></div>

<a id="test-click" href="https://google.com">link</a>

<br><br>

<a id="manual-trigger" href="https://google.com">manually trigger the click</a>
```